# How to Remove TabBar from a controller if coming in from another Tab by segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a tab bar controller which holds 5 tabs. In tab1 I have a button which bring me to my tab2. This tab2 is embedded in a navigation controller.

So how do I make the Tab bar hidden in the tab2 when i come from tab1 by segue?

In storyboard I have a made `Hide Bottom bar on push` active. Also I have written `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` in view did load of tab2.
In tab1 my prepareForSegue is like this

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ShortcutSegue" {

        let tabVc = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        tabVc.selectedIndex = 1
        tabVc.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the tab2 view controller, you can write the code below to hide the tab bar.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if let destinationTabBar = segue.destinationViewController as? UITabBarController {
    if segue.identifier == "ShortcutSegue" {
      destinationTabBar.viewControllers?.removeAtIndex(adminScreenIndex)
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can write the code below in your override func prepareForSegue method.

```
if let tabVc = segue.destinationViewController as? tab2ViewController {
  tabVc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

Or you can tick the "Hide Button Bar On Push" in the main storyboard in the attributes inspector for the tab bar view controller shown in the image below.

[Main storyboard attribute inspector "Hide Button Bar On Push"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbplX.png)

Comment: It does not work. The first solution cant be put in the tab2 controller because Tab2 is my destination VC. second solution has no effect. Third solution was already done before asking the question.